# Nancy and TinyIoC causing Stackoverflow

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

I'm working on a simple REST api to Quartz using Nancy. I have a simple context class:

```
public class QuartzContext : IQuartzContext
{
    public ISchedulerFactory Factory { get; protected set; }

    public QuartzContext(ISchedulerFactory factory)
    {
        this.Factory = factory;
    }
}
```

I'm registering an instance of the context into TinyIoC which I believe will be a singleton. Without this, the self-host fails to start due to dependency issues:

```
        TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<IQuartzContext>(
            new NancyQuartzREST.QuartzWrapper.QuartzContext(new StdSchedulerFactory()));
```

I'm using this class which is a NancyModule

```
public partial class RESTApi : NancyModule
{
    public RESTApi(IQuartzContext context) : base("/api")
    {
        this.SchedulerRoutes(context);
        this.JobRoutes(context);
        this.TriggerRoutes(context);
    }
}
```

Upon starting the self-host server, I get a stackoverflow exception - why?

Comment: Why are you trying to register into `TinyIoCContainer.Current`???

Comment: You have ISchedulrerFactory as a public property and also as an argument in a public constructor. It may be the case that TinyIoC is trying to resolve both. Can you change Factory to a private field, and check if it works?